# I can't get Math.max function to return a valid integer only #num

Tags: google-apps-script

i cant figure out how to get this code to return the highest integer and not an error
the first 8 cells in column one are all positive integers but code just returns a #num error.

this is just basic code but i tried to simplify my issue to figure out myself and same problem

}

```
function myFunction() {
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = main.getActiveSheet();
  var numbers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 8).getValues();
  var high = Math.max(numbers.);
  Logger.log(high);
```

}

Comment: `Math.max()` is used like `Math.max(10, 20);   //  20`. So how about modifying `var high = Math.max(numbers.);` to `var high = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);` or `var high = numbers.reduce(function(a, b) {return Math.max(a, b[0])});`? [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222814/7108653)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inputting an array into Math.Max in Google Apps Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202902/inputting-an-array-into-math-max-in-google-apps-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getMaxInteger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,8,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var max=vA.map(function(r){return r[0]}).sort(function(a,b){return b-a;})[0];
  Logger.log(max);
  return max;
}
```